# sorting an array with 2 factors in xcode playground

Tags: swift

I am trying to create a list of players sorted by age, but am when I write the print function I am greeted with a very strange output

my code is as follows:

```
class Player {
    let name: String
    let age: Int

    init(name : String, age: Int) {
      self.name = name
      self.age = age
    }
}

var players:[Player] = []
let player1 = Player(name: "Billy", age: 30)
let player2 = Player(name: "Peter", age: 24)
let player3 = Player(name: "John", age: 35)

players.append(player1)
players.append(player2)
players.append(player3)

let sortedPlayers = players.sorted () { $0.age < $1.age }
print(sortedPlayers)
```

Many thanks for any guidance

Comment: What output did you get?

Comment: Strange output? What output?

Comment: hi Sweeper and Larme   the output was  [__lldb_expr_101]....which i am learning is an lldb identifier

Comment: What do you expect?

Answer (score 0):

You get a generic lldb identifier when you `print` a Swift class

Adopt `CustomStringConvertible`

```
class Player : CustomStringConvertible { ...
```

and add a `description` property

```
var description : String {
    return "Player \(name), age \(age)"
}
```

or – simpler – use a struct, this avoids even the `init` method

```
struct Player {
    let name: String
    let age: Int
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for the help.  I used struct as you suggested, and removed the init. Though I am still seeing the lldb identifier, I am now seeing the sorting correctly by age (low to high)

Comment: Keep the `CustomStringConvertible` on the `struct` to not show that identifier if it bothers you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print your objects just to see if your sorting algorithm is working correctly, you just may use `dump` function like this:

```
dump(sortedPlayers)
```

The output is something like this:

```
3 elements
  SwiftPlayground.Player #0
    - name: "Peter"
    - age: 24
  SwiftPlayground.Player #1
    - name: "Billy"
    - age: 30
  SwiftPlayground.Player #2
    - name: "John"
    - age: 35
```

Comment: much appreciate....will look at the dump function aswell